# how to get geoCoordinates of a landmark on a map?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, dictionary, windows-phone, here-api

on windows phone 8, i have a page that contains a map on double click the zoom level increases. i need on click to place a landmark and get the coordinates of that landmark.

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <StackPanel Name="mapContainer" Grid.Row="0" >
                <maps:Map Name="Mymap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="{Binding ElementName=mapContainer, Path=ActualHeight}" Width="{Binding ElementName=ContentPanel,Path=ActualWidth}" LandmarksEnabled="True" MouseLeftButtonDown="Mymap_MouseLeftButtonDown"/>
            </StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a tap handler to the map.

And have the handler as follows ::

```
    private void MapControl_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        GeoCoordinate geocoordinate = this.MapControl.ConvertViewportPointToGeoCoordinate(e.GetPosition(this.MapControl));
    }
```

You will have the map coordinates in the geocoordinate object.
Hope i got the question right and the solution helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the clicked pixel location to a coordinate with [Map.ConvertViewportPointToGeoCoordinate Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.maps.controls.map.convertviewportpointtogeocoordinate%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: i have onclick event on the map so what i what i should pass ConvertViewportPointToGeoCoordinate function